# Is there a way to change the preferences of the "upgrade arrow" in the inventory screen in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The inventory screen in Skyrim offers a small upwards arrow suggesting the item is an upgrade in comparison to your currently equipped gear.

This is pretty useful when your character is carrying a lot of loot, however I have problems with it. I use light armour and every heavy armour is seen as an 'upgrade'. Same applies to weapons. I want to use a dagger, but all two handed weapons and other types of one handed weapons are also seen as an upgrade. Yes the damage/armour ratings might be higher, but it isn't exactly an upgrade for my character.

Is there any way of changing this?

Comment: Same problem for magic users... the 75% faster magicka restoration is worth more than the 5 extra armor, yet the latter receives the upgrade arrow.

Comment: I'm looking forward to mods to fix this on the PC version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to change this in the game, unfortunately. The comparison only looks at base values to see which number is bigger. Personally, I ignore it. It was better at lower levels, but now you should use your own judgment.

Comment: If you think this answer is viable enough, please make sure to check it off.

Answer (score 2):

Sell off (or store) all of the equipment that is not specific to your build and then the suggestions will be more relevant. But no there is no way to make the game take your armor preference into account.